# typo3 in news detail powermail form submit action is not working

Tags: typo3, tx-news, powermail

I have added the powermail form as content element in news. So the form is shown in news detail page but that form is not submitted, i have given flexform option to redirect at thank you page. But that is not working and always gives 404 error, and no news found error.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Documentation/FAQ/Readme.md
but in TYPO3 11
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.misc.addQueryString  = 1

Answer (score 0):

Did you saw this part in the FAQ of powermail: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/Faq/Index.html#i-want-to-use-powermail-on-a-news-detail-page-but-the-error-reason-no-news-entry-found-comes-up

Answer (score 0):

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.misc.addQueryString = 1
```

Add in TypoScript
Tested TYPO3 11